# Correct the sequence generator start number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

My PosgressSql database is allocating ids that already exist. From what I read can be a problem with sequence generator.

Seems that I get sequence corruption often, with the sequence starting number, being before, the last id in the database.

I know I can change the number in pgadmin, but how can I auto-correct this behavior in production.

I'm using python/django, it is possible to catch the error somehow, and reset the sequence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sequences it goes something like

```
select setval('foo_id_seq',max(id),true) from foo;
```

for apropriate values `'foo_id_seq'` of `foo` and `id`;